# NGiNX vs Apache: 500 error, как решить?

Tags: apache, nginx, joomla

Привет!
такой трабл - настроили связку NGiNX vs Apache через админку Plesk для ряда веб сайтов на хосте и до поры все работало прекрасно, пока на одном из них ([new-buildings.com](http://new-buildings.com)) не очистили кеш и началось!.. Сайт лежит выдавая в мир месседж:

> "Error displaying the error page: Call to a member function init() on
>   null: String could not be parsed as XML"

при том что в админку (Joomla!) заходим, однако в ней не видим раздел с настройками для стиля шаблона.. выдает тот же месседж что и на главной. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Судя по логам, выше, nginx отдает инфу штатно, а проблема со стороны apache. 
Пробовали править .htaccess но пока безуспешно, так он выглядит в данный момент:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Подправили nginx.conf как предлагают разрабы джумлы //docs.joomla.org/Nginx тоже не помогло..

Подскажите, где может быть эта засада??
Спасибо

Comment: какая версия Joomla!? какая версия PHP ? Joomla! 3.6 ?

Comment: Joomla! 3.6.5 | PHP Version 7.0.15

Comment: На сайте установлены JA T3 framework или K2 или что то в этом роде?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить содержимое вашего .htacces на 'чистый' вариант
http://htaccess.ru/cms/joomla/

Comment: Насколько мне понятно на сайте установлен компонент К2 ?

Comment: K2 нет, framework Gantry от RocketTheme. Подправил .htaccess под предложенный вами "чистовой" вариант, проблема прежняя

Comment: Подозреваю что засада на конфиге NGiNX, возможно в правах доступа (http://imgur.com/a/sp8Qt)

Comment: да возможно проблема именно в NGiNX, если есть возможность обратитесь к саппорту хостинга - это может решить проблему, так же вы можете для проверки перенести сайт Joomla на другой хост, чтобы удостовериться в работоспособности именно сайта..